# Simple constructive proof for the hyperplane separating theorem (HST)?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, constructive-mathematics

The Hyperplane Separation Theorem (HST) is usually [proved](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eaaa/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec5_gh.pdf) through the existence of a unique minimum-norm vector in a nonempty closed convex set. I think this is an existential proof which applies to infinite dimensional spaces.

However, to actually apply the result in a real world problem, one might need to find the actual numeric value of the minimum-norm vector through construction. Furthermore, constructivism is appreciated in mathematical economics and operation research mathematics.

Do we have a simple constructive proof for HST over $\mathbb R^n$ or a linear space?

> **Theorem:**
> Let $C,D$ be two closed convex sets of a $\mathbb R^n$ that do not  intersect.
> Then there exists a non-zero real vector $a$ such that $a\cdot c\geq a\cdot d$ for any $c\in C$ and any $d\in D$.

As an **example** for constructive proof I will refer to a simple proof of a very similar theorem, the von-Neumann–Morgenstern utility theorem:

> **vNM **Theroem:**** Let $\succsim \subset X\times X\subset\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$. Let $\succsim$ be complete, transitive, continuous.
>
> Let $\succsim$ also be convex: $(p,q)\in\succsim$ and $(l,m)\in\succsim$ implies $\alpha(p,q)+(1-\alpha)(l,m)\in\succsim$ for any $\alpha \in(0,1)$.
>
> Then, there exists a real vector $A$ such that: $(l,m)\in\succsim \iff A\cdot l\geq A\cdot m$.

A simple constructive proof can be [found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem#Proof_sketch). I think that a very simple constructive proof also exists for HST.

Comment: How are the convex sets given? How is compactness defined constructively?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I updated the question hope it is now clearer. I have to admit that I need help in defining compactness constructively.

Comment: The standard constructive definition is that a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it is closed and for every $\epsilon$ it can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\epsilon$. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bishop-compact+space

Comment: I think this is enough: Let $C_n$ and $D_n$ be the intersections of $C$ and $D$ with the ball of radius $n$ about the origin. Choose points $c_n$ and $d_n$ such that $$d(c_n,d_n)<\frac1n+d(C_n,D_n)$$ Let $a_n$ be a unit vector perpendicular to $d_n-c_n$, and let $a$ be the limit of the $a_n$. (One would still have to prove that the limit exists, but I think the construction works.)

Comment: @MattF. that idea works if you do it right... still your phrasing just happens to allow more than one limit point... easily fixed. There is an even more simple way to phrase this idea, but i'm quite busy with other stuff, so perhaps you can turn your remark into the desired answer...? thanx :-)

Comment: by easily fixed i mean not that such a limit can always be constructed... (it can't) but that depending on $d(C,D)$ and the respective diameters of $C,D$ we can find a sufficiently close approximating pair $c_n, d_n$ to construct an $a$ that works.

Comment: oh wait you are right sorry, i forgot that these are convex sets in which case the $a_n$ converge even if the other sequences don't...

Comment: I would imagine that one could prove this result from an appropriate constructive version of the Hahn–Banach theorem, e.g. the one in §9.3 of Bishop's 1967 book _Foundations of Constructive Analysis_.